# How to solve FailedPreconditionError?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, tensorflow

I have a small 3 layer network where I have created variables for weights and biases using initer, and I have used `tf.variables_initializer`to initialize variables as suggested by someone. Unfortunately despite initializin them, there still apears a Failed PreCondition Error. I am now out of ideas about how to solve it or what exactly is causing it.

```
with tf.compat.v1.variable_scope("weight_in", reuse=tf.compat.v1.AUTO_REUSE):
            weight_i = tf.compat.v1.get_variable("weight_input", dtype=tf.float64, shape=[self.neurons, 1], initializer=self.weight_initer)
        with tf.compat.v1.variable_scope("weight_hid", reuse=tf.compat.v1.AUTO_REUSE):   
            weight_h = tf.compat.v1.get_variable("weight_hidden", dtype=tf.float64, shape=[self.neurons, 1], initializer=self.weight_initer1)
        with tf.compat.v1.variable_scope("weight_out", reuse=tf.compat.v1.AUTO_REUSE): 
            weight_o = tf.compat.v1.get_variable("weight_input", dtype=tf.float64, shape=[4, 2], initializer=self.weight_initer2)
        with tf.compat.v1.variable_scope("bias_in", reuse=tf.compat.v1.AUTO_REUSE): 
            bias_i = tf.compat.v1.get_variable("bias_input", dtype=tf.float64, shape=[self.neurons, 1], initializer=self.bias_initer)
        with tf.compat.v1.variable_scope("bias_hid", reuse=tf.compat.v1.AUTO_REUSE): 
            bias_h = tf.compat.v1.get_variable("bias_hidden", dtype=tf.float64, shape=[self.neurons, 1], initializer=self.bias_initer1)
        with tf.compat.v1.variable_scope("bias_out", reuse=tf.compat.v1.AUTO_REUSE): 
            bias_o = tf.compat.v1.get_variable("bias_out", dtype=tf.float64, shape=[1, 4], initializer=self.bias_initer2)
       uninitialized_variables = []
        sess = tf.Session()
        print("printing the names of all variables")
        print(tf.all_variables())
        for var in tf.all_variables():
            try:
                sess.run(var)
            except tf.errors.FailedPreconditionError:
                uninitialized_variables.append(var)
        init = tf.variables_initializer(uninitialized_variables)
        sess.run(init)
```

The error is

```
FailedPreconditionError: Attewmpting to use initialized value weight_in/weight_input
```

sometimes the same error will be pointing another bias variable. I am wondering whether anyone can shed some light on how to properly create a variable and initialize it. Thank you.